# Codebuild latest node version mismatched with EC2

Tags: node.js, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

Has anyone run into the issue that Codebuild's latest version for node 14 is 14.19.**2** but EC2's latest supported version of node 14 is 14.19.**1**.

Since Codebuild doesn't support specifying minor version, I'm stuck at building with 14.19.2 and then can't deploy when the build finishes because the node version in the EC2 is mismatched.

Logs from Codebuild:

```
> [Container] 2022/05/21 14:21:15 Running command echo "Installing
> Node.js version 14 ..." Installing Node.js version 14 ...
> 
> [Container] 2022/05/21 14:21:15 Running command n $NODE_14_VERSION
>      copying : node/14.19.2    installed : v14.19.2 (with npm 6.14.17)
```

Logs from deploy to EC2:

```
[1/5] Validating package.json...

2022-05-21T06:53:18.834-07:00   error my-app@0.1.2: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "14.19.1". Got "14.19.2"

2022-05-21T06:53:18.834-07:00   error Found incompatible module.
```

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect, but I changed my package.json to allow both versions and now it builds and deploys.

```
"engines": {
  "node": "14.X"
},
```

It's still weird that Codebuild would support a higher version that EC2.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it yet, but maybe this way it could be done.

```yaml
# buildspec.yml
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - n 14.19.1 # specify version
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - node -v
```

FYI: https://blog.serverworks.co.jp/specific-nodejs-version-in-codebuild